# Filter GROUP BY results with another GROUP BY to trim down

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I already have a base query to select all Locations from my database, and then group them by the first 2 characters of their postcode.

```
SELECT LEFT(`locationPostcode`, 2) as `postcode`, count(`locationPostcode`) as `locationCount`
FROM `locations`
WHERE `locationPostcode` IS NOT NULL
AND `locationPostcode` <> ''
GROUP BY `postcode`
ORDER BY `locationCount` DESC
```

Because some postcodes only start with 1 alpha character, rather than 2, I need to group this again to get those postcodes (for example E1, W2) to only show their first letter.

My attempt at this is to group them again by `LEFT('postcode', 2)` but it doesn't seem to have much effect (query below)

```
SELECT postcode, locationCount FROM (

    SELECT LEFT(`locationPostcode`, 2) as `postcode`, count(`locationPostcode`) as `locationCount`
    FROM `locations`
    WHERE `locationPostcode` IS NOT NULL
    AND `locationPostcode` <> ''
    GROUP BY `postcode`
    ORDER BY `locationCount` DESC
    ) as `outer`
GROUP BY left(`postcode`, 1)
ORDER BY `locationCount` DESC
```

**clarification**: I want my actual postcode results to be as follows:

```
postcode | count
----------------
E        | 3000
W        | 2200
SW       | 1300
```

Rather than :

```
postcode | count
----------------
SW       | 1300
E1       | 1000
E2       | 300
S1       | 200
S2       | 100
S3       | 50
```

Comment: The general GROUP BY rule says: If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  From what you describe, can't you just replace "2" with "1" in the first query?

Comment: These seem to be UK post codes, in this case you can have numbers 1 to 9 as the 2nd character

Comment: @shadow sorry I didn't clarify. I'm grouping all postcodes by the 2 letters at the start. I want all postcodes with a number as the second character to be grouped together (e1, e2, e3 etc all in E group)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The description of your issue suggests a conditional case for the `group by`:

```
SELECT (case when substr(locationPostcode, 2, 1) between 'A' and 'Z'
             then left(`locationPostcode`, 2)
             else left(locationPostcode, 1)
        end) as postcode_prefix, count(`locationPostcode`) as `locationCount`
FROM `locations`
WHERE `locationPostcode` IS NOT NULL AND `locationPostcode` <> ''
GROUP BY postcode_prefix
ORDER BY `locationCount` DESC;
```

Comment: Perfect! exactly what I needed - being a newbie to sql, I didn't realise conditionals were available